# Two distribution spaces ${\mathcal S}'/{\mathcal P}$ and ${\mathcal S}_\infty'$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let ${\mathcal S}'$ be the set of all distributions.
Denote by ${\mathcal P}$ the set of all polynomials,
which is embedded into ${\mathcal S}'$ as a closed subspace.
Equip ${\mathcal S'}/{\mathcal P}$ with the quotient topology.

It is known that ${\mathcal S}'/{\mathcal P}$ is algebraically isomorphic
to the dual of ${\mathcal S}_{\infty}$, where ${\mathcal S}_\infty$ is the set of all
$f \in {\mathcal S}$ for which ${\mathcal F}f=O(|\xi|^m)$ for all $m \in {\mathcal N}$.
My question is as follows:
If ${\mathcal S}_\infty'$, the dual of ${\mathcal S}_\infty$, is equipped 
with the weak topology, then can we say that ${\mathcal S}_\infty'$ and ${\mathcal S}'/{\mathcal P}$ is topologicall isomorphic ?

Comment: This question would benefit from some further explanation. For instance, when you say ${\cal F}f=O(|\xi|^m)$, you mean $\xi\to 0$ rather than $\xi\to\infty$, right? Otherwise, this does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Dear Professor Michael Renardy, I am sorry for my delay in reply. Yes, I meant $\xi \to 0$.